# need to convert monard chainrl to applicative style

Tags: parsing, haskell

Hi have parser using monard

```
chainr1 p op = scan
where scan   = p >>= rest
    rest x = do f <- op
                y <- scan
                return (f x y)
             +++ return
```

Comment: And why do you need to convert that?

Comment: It is by the way *monad*, not *monard*.

Comment: What is by the way `v`? The parser for a single element?

Comment: It's not Stack Overflow's job to write your program for you. Please include attempts you have made and what went wrong, and Stack Overflow can help you understand better.

Answer (score 1):

Given this:

```
do
  f <- op
  y <- scan
  return (f x y)
```

You could desugar `do` notation and then use rewriting rules to arrive at an applicative version, but the simpler method is to recognise the pattern of parsing `op` then `scan` and combining them somehow with a function:

```
do
  a <- …
  b <- …
  return (… a … b …)
```

For this pattern you can use `liftA2` or `… <$> … <*> …`:

```
liftA2 (\ f y -> f x y) op scan

(\ f y -> f x y) <$> op <*> scan
```

You can then eta-reduce `y`:

```
(\ f -> f x) <$> op <*> scan
```

And then make it point-free using an operator section with `($)`:

```
($ x) <$> op <*> scan
```

`($ x)` or `flip ($) x` is a function that takes a function and applies it to `x`, e.g. `map ($ 2) [(* 3), (+ 5)] == [6, 7]`.

Answer (score 0):

Put `{-# LANGUAGE ApplicativeDo #-}` at the top of your file, and your `do` block will then be desugared to use `Applicative` instead of `Monad`. Also, you should change your `return` to `pure`.